# React Profiler - Can I determine what causes extra commits (grey)?

Tags: reactjs, performance, profiler

I am trying to solve a performance issue with a component that is nested within a few layers. When using the React Profiler (React 16.5.2) I can see timings and commits, but I'm see a surprising number of 100% grey commits between active ones. In the following picture there are 16 blank commits for every one meaningful commit:

[image: Example of extra grey commits]

**How can I determine where these extra commits originate from**? I see a ~1-2s lag time before the component visually updates, and I am trying to nail down if it is these large gaps of grey commits that might be delaying meaningful commits.

### Edit: More Info -

All components in the chain are pure. Only one component makes use of additional lifecycle methods and it's `componentDidUpdate` to add/remove a listener to the document.

Comment: You would need the flame chart to explain this better.

Comment: How can it help? It shows the tree but all components are grey showing no timing so I assume no changes. Is there more information I can gain from it than that?

Comment: I think Orar means to take a trace in the Timeline tab in Chrome's dev tools and see which JS callstacks are taking up this time.